# Metadata editor for quicktime (.mov) files

Tags: macos, video, metadata, quicktime, exiftool

My photo camera records video as .mov files. They have some metadata (in the XMP format?), which I can read using `exiftool`. For example, to get only the metadata related to dates/times I can do:

```
$ exiftool MVI_3735.MOV | grep -i Date
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:09:09 20:40:33+01:00
Date/Time Original              : 2013:09:09 18:46:15
Create Date                     : 2013:09:09 18:46:15
Modify Date                     : 2013:09:09 18:46:15
Track Create Date               : 2013:09:09 18:46:15
Track Modify Date               : 2013:09:09 18:46:15
Media Create Date               : 2013:09:09 18:46:15
Media Modify Date               : 2013:09:09 18:46:15
```

**What I need is to make all the dates/times equal to the file's date/time (the first line in the example above). Any idea how I can accomplish this on OSX?**

Additionally, it would be great if it allowed me to shift any existing time value by a duration amount, like exiftool does (e.g., "add 2h to Create Date"), and if allows me to do this for a whole set of files, but I can manage if I have to edit the metadata for each file individually.

**What I've tried so far**

- **ExifTool.** That's what I would use if it were jpegs, but it doesn't seem to be able to write metadata of mov files. It is just able to read it...
- **[Hootenanny](http://www.applesolutions.com/bantha/MH.html).** It doesn't seem to read the original metadata. In spite of that, it allows me to add a `Creation Date` and a `Modify Date`, and when I reload the file it is able to read *that* info. So, my conclusion is that it's storing metadata somewhere else (i.e., not in the same place my camera is storing it). Plus, just adding a `Creation Date` and saving adds 200k to the file. For all of this, I'm not considering this a reliable solution.
- **ffmpeg.** This should work, and I've tried running it on the command line, but the result seems to be that a big chunk of the existing metadata disappears (!) and the `Creation Date` ends up not being saved anyway: `ffmpeg -i MVI_3735.MOV -metadata creation_time='2013:09:09 20:40:33' -codec copy MVI_3735_withdate.MOV`